# Guice injection in a jenkins plugin?

Tags: jenkins, guice, jenkins-plugins

I just wrote this wiki page on how to do dependency injection in a plugin:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Dependency+Injection

I want to use this so that I can provide a move requests to external resource to a service class and pass a mock to my Publisher during unit tests.

The problem with the example I gave in the wiki is that I cannot provide a mock easily:

```
@Override
public boolean perform(AbstractBuild<?, ?> build, Launcher launcher, BuildListener listener)
{
    Guice.createInjector(new MyModule()).injectMembers(this);
    // ...
    mySvc.myServiceMethod(); // "it works!"
}
```

I need to remove that Guice.createInjector() line.

Is it possible to mark the AbstractModule subclass to be 'picked up' by Guice? I tried marking it with @Exension from comments here https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-8751 but it's not being injected.

Comment: I'm using @Extension for my AbstractModule and it's being picked up by Guice. Probably check your Jenkins version? Also I've been searching like this in Google to get more reference about Guice: `site:https://github.com/jenkinsci AbstractModule`