# Dependency injection in Jenkins development

Tags: java, jenkins, dependency-injection

I'm working on an (existing) Jenkins plugin and would like to use dependency injection. Unfortunately, DI for Jenkins development is poorly documented. As far as I know Jenkins uses Google's Guice framework for DI. There is [this Wiki page](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Dependency+Injection), but I'm a little puzzled about it: in existing Jenkins plugins that I've checked I don't see such calls to Guice, but I do see plenty of uses of the `@Inject` annotation. Futhermore, it bothers me that I would need to call `Guice.createInjector(new MyModule()).injectMembers(this);` inside *every* class where I want dependency injection, it seems like I'm littering my code.

How do I do dependency injection in Jenkins? For example, I have a simple interface "MyInterface" and an implementing class `MyInterfaceImpl`. In a third class I have the following:

```
class MyClass {
    private MyInterface obj;

    @Inject
    public MyClass(MyInterface obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    ...
}
```

Is there a mechanism in Jenkins to automatically construct such objects, or do I have to add that Guice injector code?

Comment: Did you try to copy the whole example and just the example? It is implied that MyGuiceModule will be picked up by Jenkins through class path scanning and that Jenkins will handle the DI from there on out.

Comment: Well what's puzzling me is I don't see the usage of Guice's `AbstractModule` class in existing Jenkins plugins, but plenty of uses of `@Inject`. An example is this plugin: https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-plugin. So how is that code accomplishing DI?

Comment: It appears that the plugin uses an `@Extension` annotation to mark the components for DI. https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/08def67a18eee51de9f3f99bc2a792fee1c160e0/core/src/main/java/hudson/Extension.java

Answer (score 2):

You should not need to touch Guice. Define an interface (extending `ExtensionPoint` as a matter of documentation); implement it as an `@Extension`; and look up implementations using `ExtensionList`. `JenkinsRule`-based tests can use `@TestExtension` to add mock implementations. Note that properly speaking this a service registry, not dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

The wiki with the incomplete information was written by [Dan Alvizux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27849291/guice-injection-in-a-jenkins-plugin) as part of a SO question. It does not reflect how Jenkins actually does its DI.

The correct way to register a class for DI appears to be annotating it with [`@Extension`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/08def67a18eee51de9f3f99bc2a792fee1c160e0/core/src/main/java/hudson/Extension.java) and using `@Inject` as normally. There are some other options discussed in the JavaDoc.

Comment: From the JavaDoc it's still not clear whether or not the DI mechanism for classes annotated with @Extension only applies to classes actually implementing a [Jenkins extension point](https://jenkins.io/doc/developer/extensions/), or for any arbitrary class that requires DI for arbitrary dependencies. I've had no success yet playing around with this in code ...